# Formatting byte[] or ReadOnlySpan<byte> to string using C# 10 and .NET 6 string interpolation, compiler handler lowering pattern

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to format `byte[]` and `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` bytes to strings using a few, custom formatting parameters. Say, like `S` for `Base64`. For the purpose of this, the length is always fixed to some known constant.

I would like to use the modern C# 10 and .NET 6 string formatting capabilities as described at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/string-interpolation-in-c-10-and-net-6/. The built-in types implement [ISpanFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.ispanformattable) and so what I'd like to bring here is new formatting parameters but so that compiler [handler lowering pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-interpolated-strings) is used.

I took some code from that post and modified it a bit in the code embedded as follows. It's also at https://dotnetfiddle.net/svyQKD.

As is seen in the code, I get the direct method call to succeed for `byte[]`, but not for `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

I suspect I need [InterpolatedStringHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/interpolated-string-handler). But if that is the case, then it looks like I don't know how to implement one. All tips and code tricks would probably help. I've been stuck at this for a while now and it's getting into wee hours. :)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Program
{
    public sealed class ExampleCustomFormatter: IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        public object? GetFormat(Type? formatType) => formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter) ? this : null;
        public string Format(string? format, object? arg, IFormatProvider? formatProvider) => format == "S" && arg is byte[] i ? Convert.ToBase64String(i) : arg is IFormattable formattable ? formattable.ToString(format, formatProvider) : arg?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string FormatString(byte[] buffer) => string.Create(new ExampleCustomFormatter(), stackalloc char[64], $"{buffer:S}");

        // How to make this work? Maybe needs to have TryWrite 
        // public static string FormatString2(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer) => string.Create(new ExampleCustomFormatter(), stackalloc char[64], $"{buffer:S}");
    }

    [InterpolatedStringHandler]
    public ref struct BinaryMessageInterpolatedStringHandler
    {
        private readonly DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler handler;

        public BinaryMessageInterpolatedStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount, bool predicate, out bool handlerIsValid)
        {
            handler = default;

            if(predicate)
            {
                handlerIsValid = false;
                return;
            }

            handlerIsValid = true;
            handler = new DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler(literalLength, formattedCount);
        }

        public void AppendLiteral(string s) => handler.AppendLiteral(s);

        public void AppendFormatted<T>(T t) => handler.AppendFormatted(t);

        public override string ToString() => handler.ToStringAndClear();
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] test1 = new byte[1] { 0x55 };
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> test2 = new byte[1] { 0x55 };

        // How to make this work? Now it prints "System.Byte[]".
        Console.WriteLine($"{test1:S}");

        // This works.
        Console.WriteLine(StringExtensions.FormatString(test1));

        // How to make this work? This does not compile. (Yes, signature problem. How to define it?).
        // Console.WriteLine($"{test2:S}");

        // How to make this work? This does not compile. (Yes, signature problem. How to define it?).

        // Console.WriteLine(StringExtensions.FormatString(test2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interpolated string handlers are intended for writing the result into a buffer with fewer allocations. You can't change which handler `.WriteLine` uses. Also handlers don't implement an interface, nor is supporting handler extension methods a design goal. I'd recommend `byte[]` and `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` extension methods.

Comment: The `Console.WriteLine` is for illustrative purposes but may be on target eventually. You can see `stackalloc` used as for an example. So, I am looking at allocating a buffer and using the lowering mechanism the compiler can use and aid but for custom formatting. I imagine I could make use of [ISpanFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.ispanformattable) that the built-in types use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with this as I was also interested in learning about these handlers, so consider my answer with some suspicion.

The build error `CS0306 The type 'ReadOnlySpan<byte>' may not be used as a type argument` on `Console.WriteLine($"{test2:S}");` (and `StringExtensions.FormatString2`) stem from (I believe) the compiler-generated call to `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted<T>` with generic type argument `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` which is illegal (`ReadOnlySpan` is a `ref struct` and a `ref struct` cannot be used as a type argument).

As explained in Stephen Toub's blog which you linked, the compiler will happily expand any interpolated string to use `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` (if it so desires) which is why you may use an interpolated string with `Console.WriteLine` even if it does not have an overload taking a `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` parameter:

```
// This trivial example might not actually construct a DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler
// but the point still stands (it compiles and works)
int x = 3;
Console.WriteLine($"{x}");
```

An easy solution would have been to create an extension overload of `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler.AppendFormatted` taking a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` but in this cruel world the compiler does not appear to detect it:

```
public static class PleaseWork
{
    public static void AppendFormatted(
        this ref DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler handler,
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes,
        string? format)
    {
        if (format != "S")
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format");
        }

        handler.AppendLiteral(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
    }
}

ReadOnlySpan<byte> test2 = new byte[1] { 0x56 };
Console.WriteLine($"{test2:S}"); // nope (CS0306)
```

So here is a solution: create a custom `InterpolatedStringHandler` (as you have done) with the `AppendFormatted` overload. Like in your implementation we can just wrap a `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler` (or a `StringBuilder`) so that the actual implementation (buffer management etc) is left to the more clever folk. Full example:

```
public class Program
{
    [InterpolatedStringHandler]
    public ref struct WrappingInterpolatedStringHandler
    {
        private DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler handler;

        public WrappingInterpolatedStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount)
        {
            handler = new(literalLength, formattedCount);
        }

        public void AppendLiteral(string s) => handler.AppendLiteral(s);

        public void AppendFormatted<T>(T t, string? format = null)
            => handler.AppendFormatted(t, format);

        // This is necessary otherwise byte[] arg resolves to the generic overload
        public void AppendFormatted(byte[] bytes, string? format = null)
            => AppendFormatted((ReadOnlySpan<byte>)bytes, format);

        public void AppendFormatted(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes, string? format)
        {
            if (format != "S")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format");
            }
            
            // This allocates an intermediate string
            handler.AppendLiteral(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
        }

        public string ToStringAndClear() => handler.ToStringAndClear();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] test1 = new byte[1] { 0x55 };
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> test2 = new byte[1] { 0x56 };
        Span<byte> test3 = new byte[128];
        test3.Fill(0x55);

        WriteLine($"test1:{test1:S}"); // "test1:VQ=="
        WriteLine($"test2:{test2:S}"); // "test2:Vg=="
        WriteLine($"test3:{test3:S}"); // "test3:<a long base64 string>"
    }

    private static void WriteLine(ref WrappingInterpolatedStringHandler builder)
    {
        // Naturally, Console.WriteLine has no overload taking our custom handler
        // so we need to give it the resulting string
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToStringAndClear());
    }
}
```

Our new `AppendFormatted` overload calls `Convert.ToBase64String` which is allocating an intermediate `string` (which is then copied into the buffer of the `DefaultInterpolatedStringHandler`). That's the (vanishingly small?) price we pay for not managing the buffer ourselves. If we couldn't bear the thought (to hell with implementation risk and diminishing returns), here is a dumb handler taking a (fixed size) buffer as an argument (which can be stack-allocted):

```
public class Program
{
    [InterpolatedStringHandler]
    public ref struct MyReallyBadAndUntestedInterpolatedStringHandler
    {
        private readonly Span<char> _buffer;
        private int _charsWritten;

        public MyReallyBadAndUntestedInterpolatedStringHandler(int literalLength, int formattedCount, Span<char> destination)
        {
            _buffer = destination;
            _charsWritten = 0;
        }

        public bool AppendLiteral(string s)
        {
            if (s.AsSpan().TryCopyTo(_buffer.Slice(_charsWritten)))
            {
                _charsWritten += s.Length;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public bool AppendFormatted<T>(T t, ReadOnlySpan<char> format)
        {
            Span<char> buffer = _buffer.Slice(_charsWritten);
            
            if (t is ISpanFormattable formattable)
            {
                bool success = formattable.TryFormat(buffer, out int charsWritten, format, null);
                _charsWritten += charsWritten;
                return success;
            }

            string s = t?.ToString() ?? "";

            if (s.AsSpan().TryCopyTo(buffer))
            {
                _charsWritten += s.Length;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        // This is necessary otherwise byte[] arg resolves to the generic overload
        public bool AppendFormatted(byte[] bytes, ReadOnlySpan<char> format)
            => AppendFormatted((ReadOnlySpan<byte>)bytes, format);

        public bool AppendFormatted(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes, ReadOnlySpan<char> format)
        {
            if (format != "S")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid format");
            }

            bool success = Convert.TryToBase64Chars(bytes, _buffer.Slice(_charsWritten), out int charsWritten);
            _charsWritten += charsWritten;
            return success;
        }

        public string ToStringAndClear()
        {
            string result = new string(_buffer.Slice(0, _charsWritten));
            _buffer.Clear();
            _charsWritten = 0;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] test1 = new byte[1] { 0x55 };
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> test2 = new byte[1] { 0x56 };
        Span<byte> test3 = new byte[128];
        test3.Fill(0x55);

        Span<char> buffer = stackalloc char[64];
        WriteLine(buffer, $"test1:{test1:S}"); // "test1:VQ=="
        WriteLine(buffer, $"test2:{test2:S}"); // "test2:Vg=="
        WriteLine(buffer, $"test3:{test3:S}"); // "test3:" (the buffer is not big enough)
    }

    private static void WriteLine(
        Span<char> destination,
        [InterpolatedStringHandlerArgument("destination")] ref MyReallyBadAndUntestedInterpolatedStringHandler builder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToStringAndClear());
    }
}
```

In conclusion just call `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(test2))` and move on :)

Comment: I went ahead and changed to this, even if a lot late. I was doing this more about of curiosity back then, approximately following similar logic. If I remember something really. But I'm delighted to see you could actually pull it off. Sometimes it's nice to push the boundaries of code and understanding a bit. To find out how things work. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the method like this, you need to override the `ToString()` method of the class `Byte[]`.

But you cannot override the method on the very class `Byte[]`. You need to inherit the class `Byte[]` and override the `ToString()` method on the derived.

Then, you must replace all your `Byte[]` objects with the derived class, with is not a good idea.

So, there is no solution for you in this manner:

```
// How to make this work? Now it prints "System.Byte[]".
Console.WriteLine($"{test1:S}");
```

The best you can do is create an "outside" method for formatting the `Byte[]` and do as you with for formatting.

*The same applies to the `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension method:

```cs
using System.Text;

byte[] test1 = new byte[2] { 0x55, 0x34 };
ReadOnlySpan<byte> test2 = new byte[2] { 0x55, 0x34 };

// How to make this work? Now it prints "System.Byte[]".
Console.WriteLine($"{test1.MyFormat()}");

Console.WriteLine($"{test2.MyFormat()}");

public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static string MyFormat(this byte[] value)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in value)
        {
            sb.Append(b).Append(" ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string MyFormat(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> value)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in value)
        {
            sb.Append(b).Append(" ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
85 52
85 52
```

You can try also with:

```cs
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static string MyFormat(this byte[] value) => Encoding.Unicode.GetString(value);

    public static string MyFormat(this ReadOnlySpan<byte> value) => Encoding.Unicode.GetString(value);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate coming up with this, but I'm looking to make use of the [handler lowering pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-interpolated-strings) as explained in the blog and that document. This to add a few custom formatting parameters with a buffer to types that seem to implement [ISpanFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.ispanformattable) already.

Comment: I'll accept this one to close this and move on.

To those who are reading, I made some progress with using handler and making this a good experience. One issue ref struct as an argument, but doable to improve programmer experience ("ReadOnlySpan<byte> may not be used as a type argument").